# How to correctly call fnd_concurrent.wait_for_request stored function via cx_Oracle module API?

Tags: python, oracle, plsql, cx-oracle

I am trying to perform wait for submitted request in Oracle by calling `fnd_concurrent.wait_for_request` stored procedure using Python cx_Oracle module, but facing an error: `cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error`

FND_CONCURRENT.WAIT_FOR_REQUEST have the following signature:
(from doc https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18727_01/doc.121/e12897/T302934T458258.htm)

```
function FND_CONCURRENT.WAIT_FOR_REQUEST  

(request_id IN number default NULL,
          interval   IN number default 60,
          max_wait   IN number default 0,
          phase      OUT varchar2,
          status     OUT varchar2,
          dev_phase  OUT varchar2,
          dev_status OUT varchar2,
          message    OUT varchar2) return  boolean;
```

and I calling it with python code:

```
...
lc_phase = cursor.var(str)
lc_status = cursor.var(str)
lc_dev_phase = cursor.var(str)
lc_dev_status = cursor.var(str)
lc_message = cursor.var(str)

bool_result = cursor.callfunc('fnd_concurrent.wait_for_request', bool, [123456789,5,15,lc_phase,lc_status,lc_dev_phase,lc_dev_status,lc_message])

print('fnd_concurrent.wait_for_request result: ', bool_result)
...
```

I did try different types for out parameters like `cx_Oracle.DB_TYPE_VARCHAR` and `cx_Oracle.STRING` but with same result.

Error describes that issue with exact line with `cursor.callfunc()` call

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see an error with this test case:

```
import cx_Oracle
import os
import sys

"""

create or replace function my_wait_for_request
  (request_id IN number default NULL,
          interval   IN number default 60,
          max_wait   IN number default 0,
          phase      OUT varchar2,
          status     OUT varchar2,
          dev_phase  OUT varchar2,
          dev_status OUT varchar2,
          message    OUT varchar2) return boolean
as
begin
  phase := 'my phase';
  status := 'my status';
  dev_phase := 'my dev_phase';
  dev_status := 'my dev_status';
  message := 'my message';
  return(true);
end;
/

show errors

"""

if sys.platform.startswith("darwin"):
    cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=os.environ.get("HOME")+"/Downloads/instantclient_19_8")

username = os.environ.get("PYTHON_USERNAME")
password = os.environ.get("PYTHON_PASSWORD")
connect_string = os.environ.get("PYTHON_CONNECTSTRING")

connection = cx_Oracle.connect(username, password, connect_string)

cursor = connection.cursor()

lc_phase = cursor.var(str)
lc_status = cursor.var(str)
lc_dev_phase = cursor.var(str)
lc_dev_status = cursor.var(str)
lc_message = cursor.var(str)

bool_result = cursor.callfunc('my_wait_for_request', bool, [123456789,5,15,lc_phase,lc_status,lc_dev_phase,lc_dev_status,lc_message])

print('my_wait_for_request result: ', bool_result)
print(lc_phase.getvalue(),lc_status.getvalue(),lc_dev_phase.getvalue(),lc_dev_status.getvalue(),lc_message.getvalue())
```

The output was:

```
my_wait_for_request result:  True
my phase my status my dev_phase my dev_status my message
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Looks like issue was in bool conversion that is solved here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68381983/expresssion-is-of-wrong-type-when-calling-function-using-cx-oracle. Unclear for now why your testcase is working. Maybe different version of cx_Oralce. I'ts 8.2.1 for me

Comment: I used 8.2.1 with 19.8 Instant Client.